# Concepts of BlocListener, BlocBuilder, and BlocProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am having difficulty understanding this structure. My idea is simple: I have a MultiBlocProvider in my build with two BlocProviders. The first one uses AuthBloc and immediately calls my GetToken, and the second one prepares my provider (TokenBloc).

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MultiBlocProvider(
    providers: [
      BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
        create: (context) => sl()..add(const GetToken()),
      ),
      BlocProvider<TokenBloc>(
        create: (context) => sl<TokenBloc>(),
      ),
    ],
    child: ...
  );
}
```

In my StatefulWidget:

```
body: BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthBlocState>(
  builder: (_, state) {
    if (state is AuthLoading) {
      return const Center(child: CupertinoActivityIndicator());
    }
    if (state is AuthError) {
      return const Center(child: CupertinoActivityIndicator());
    }
    if (state is AuthDone) {
      return Container() // #MORE
    }
    ...
  }
)
```

So far, everything is fine. My container is only displayed when the state is AuthDone. However, in my widget, at #MORE, I have a button that should trigger (onTap) a method called _go():

```
_go() async {
  BlocProvider.of<TokenBloc>(context).add(const GetToken());
}
```

Here everything is great; it works. However, I wanted to create a listener to track the states and at the same time execute other functions (without involving the creation of widgets). As far as I understood, the step was:

```
go() async {
  BlocProvider<TokenBloc>(
    create: (context) => sl()..add(const GetToken()),
    child: BlocListener<TokenBloc, TokenBlocState>(
      listenWhen: (previousState, currentState) {
        debugPrint("E1");
        debugPrint(currentState.data!.toString());
        return currentState is TokenDone ||
            currentState is TokenLoading;
      },
      listener: (_, state) {
        debugPrint(state.toString());
        if (state is TokenLoading) {
          debugPrint("LOADING");
        }
        if (state is TokenError) {
          debugPrint("ERROR");
        }
        if (state is TokenDone) {
          debugPrint("DONE");
        }
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

With this change, it no longer triggers my API or the BlocListener. This method needs to be separated from the widget because it will do something else.

I really thought I was following the right path. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BlocListener` is a widget. It needs to be in the widget tree to properly work, the widget tree being what you return in the `build` method of your widgets (or their states in case of stateful widgets).

Under the hood, `BlocListener` gets the bloc/cubit from the context in `initState` and listens on it, applies the condition `listenWhen` and calls the `listener` method.

If you want to create a listener on your cubit/bloc outside of the widget-tree, like on a button click, you can do it like you would with the `Stream`:

```dart
BlocProvider.of<TokenBloc>(context).stream.listen((state) {
  // state is of TokenBlocState type
});
```

The [`listen`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/listen.html) method returns a `StreamSubscription` that you need to `cancel` when you no longer need the subscription.

But I see you're listening in the (what I assume is) some button callback. You probably want to check the current state of the bloc, not listen for the changes. Then you can just get the `state` of the bloc like so:

```dart
final state = BlocProvider.of<TokenBloc>(context).state;
// state is of TokenBlocState type
```

Regarding the `BlocProvider` widget that you put above `BlocListener` in your `go()` method - you probably want to use the bloc you already provided somewhere else, higher in the widget tree, not create a new instance. If the `BlocProvider` was outside of your widget, you can get it through `BlocProvider.of(context)` like in the example above. If it is in the same widget as the method, you need to pass to the `.of()` method a `BuildContext` that contains this provider, so wrap your widget with `Builder` widget and pass the `context` to your `go()` method.